# Change the querystring using RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to replace the part of the given URL using button click.When I click play button need change `autoplay=0 to autoplay=1` and When I click close button need change `autoplay=1 to autoplay=0`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.playButton').click(function() {
    alert('play');
    $("iframe").src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 1);
  });

  $(".close_icon").click(function() {
    alert('close');
    $("iframe").src = src.replace(/\&autoplay\=\d/, "&autoplay=" + 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640&autoplay=1"></iframe>
<div class="playButton">Play</div>
<div class="close_icon">Close</div>
```

Comment: Use `attr()` to change the `src` attribute of iframe. `$('iframe').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) { return oldSrc.replace('autoplay=0', 'autoplay=1'); });`

Comment: @tushar your post is working fine.Please post it again

Comment: Here is [complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vqzkn1gp/)

Comment: post your ans.I'll upvote your answer

Comment: _I need to check autoplay is in src and then append_ So, there can be cases when there is no `autoplay=n` in the URL?

Comment: can you update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need RegEx for this. String replacement can be done.

`$("iframe").src` will not set the value of `src` attribute of `iframe`. Use `attr()` to change the attribute of an element.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.playButton').click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
      if (oldSrc.indexOf('autoplay') === -1) {
        // If autoplay is not on URL, add it
        oldSrc += '&autoplay=1';
      }

      return oldSrc.replace('autoplay=0', 'autoplay=1');
    });
  });

  $(".close_icon").click(function() {
    $("iframe").attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
      return oldSrc.replace('autoplay=1', 'autoplay=0');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?width=640"></iframe>
<div class="playButton">Play</div>
<div class="close_icon">Close</div>
```

---

The code can be DRY'd as follow

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // To update the value of autoplay in the URL of iframe src attribute
    var changeAutoplay = function(newValue) {
        $('iframe').attr('src', function(i, oldSrc) {
            return oldSrc.replace(/autoplay=\d/, 'autoplay=' + newValue);
        });
    };

    $('.playButton').click(function() {
        changeAutoplay(1);
    });

    $(".close_icon").click(function() {
        changeAutoplay(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to check autoplay is in src and then append

Comment: @user3386779 To check if a string exists in other string, you can use `indexOf()`. In your case you can also use `/autoplay=\d/.test(url)`

Comment: @user3386779 I've added condition in `if` in the `play` callback. I guess there is no need to do same in `stop` callback.

Comment: @user3386779 I've removed the `autoplay` from the URL in the above snippet. You can see `autoplay` is added when you click on `play` button.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, there is an error from the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: src is not defined`, which means that you try to use non-existent property, try with:

```
$("iframe").attr("src", function(index, value){ return value.replace("autoplay=0", "autoplay=1") })
```

Read more about `attr` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function).